# Jquery ajax webmethod vs webserrvice webmethod?

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

What is the difference between (Webmethod) defined on aspx.cs for an ajax call and `Webmethod` in a `webservice`?

Does internally `jqueryajax` makes a `webservice` call to a method is aspx.cs file so it requires method to have `webmethod` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. jQuery's ajax does not call a web service, exactly, it calls a method. Using the `[WebMethod]` attribute allows a method to be used by front-end script. The difference is just the end point. One is in a page's code-behind, the other in a web service.

I think the idea is that you could make a web service findable by an outside source, but an outside source couldn't find a `WebMethod` in code behind. (Not 100% sure but I think that's right.) You could also group a lot of related code in a web service but place one or two methods in code behind.